# How to make design css for UI mobile layout in portrait and landscape mode

Tags: html, css, user-interface, ionic-framework, bootstrap-4

[Sample image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQnWI.jpg)

*NB : - The red color is background
      - The blue color is image

How to code the `UI` from portrait mode to landscape mode in mobile view using `CSS`/`Bootstrap` or something else, I'm using `ionic` to developed this.

this is my code :

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content class="padding" style="background-color:#616161">
        <div class="row row-center row-assertive" style="margin:3px auto;">
          <div class="col col-50" align="center">
            <a ng-click="secu()">
                <img class="shadow" src="img/i-security.png" style=" max-width: 100%">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col col-50" align="center">
            <a ng-click="trip()">
                <img class="shadow" src="img/i-trip.png" style=" max-width: 100%">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-center row-royal" style="margin:3px auto;"> 
          <div class="col col-50" align="center">
            <a ng-click="find()">
                <img class="shadow" src="img/i-find.png" style="width:97%">
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col col-50" align="center">
            <a ng-click="logout()">
                <img class="shadow" src="img/i-setting.png" style="width:97%">
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?
Also please edit your question to adhere to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i have tried in grid baic from ionic, table with bootstrap and another. yes

Answer (score 1):

Portrait/Landscape depends upon the device screen-width. When you shift device into Landscape mode its dimensions get reversed i.e, height becomes width and width becomes height. So in order to achieve the above image you need to write  two different "MEDIA QUERIES" with  two different screen width to make it responsive. Post your code.

Comment: But you need to understand the concept of "media queries" to make a dynamic /responsive page for different  kind of  screen sizes.  For testing your code in different type of screen sizes you can use  developer tools( In google chrome press F12 and click on responsive button)

Answer (score 1):

You can use media query for this

> Following works on portrait view

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) {
   /* Add css here */
}
```

> Following works on landscape view

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) {
   /* Add css here */
}
```

For more detail please visit :

**[media for orientation](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-orientation-styles/)**

**[media query](https://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)**

Comment: my app just for android device and i want to my app look like a app from samsun* the app name is **Smart Manager**

Comment: yes, but i didn't look the match answer from my question

Comment: Are you looking for the blue box center in red box vertically and horizontally ?

Comment: i'm looking for the blue box in portrait mode the size same with red box and in the landscape mode i want the blue box center in red box horizontally and the size not bigger than red box verically, conclusion in portrait mode image big and the landscape mode image smaller not more bigger red box.

Comment: use flex css properties for it.

Comment: it can apply on ionic css

Comment: thanks lokesh, but when i trying to use flex css properties is not same with my opinion in ionic css